# Match regular expression without slash in URL-like string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regular expression `#^en/cities/(.*?)/$#` and I want it to match anything, but stop at the first slash.

I.e. it should match 'paris' but not 'paris/france' if someone manages to type that URL.

I thought I already had it as non-greedy with the questionmark, but apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negated character class.

```
#^en/cities/([^/]+)/$#
```

In your regex the non-greediness failed because you anchored the last slash to the end (`$`). Removing that would also make your regex work:

```
#^en/cities/.*?/#
```

Comment: No need for the `?` in your first example.

Comment: @ridgerunner - Hm, I think you might be mistaken. The delimeter here is `#` (in case that's what you missed) so the non-greedy quantifier must seek until a `/` is matched.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I did miss the `/`. Comment retracted. Sorry bout that! +1